# Is 'copy' command in Amazon RedShift atomic or not?

Tags: amazon-redshift

For Amazon RedShift, usually data are loaded from S3 using 'copy' command. I want to know if the command is atomic or not. E.g. is it possible that in some exceptional cases that only part of the data file is loaded into RedShift table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The COPY command with default options is atomic. If the file includes an invalid line that can cause a load failure, the COPY transaction will be rollbacked and no data is imported.

If you want to skip invalid lines and not to stop the transaction, you can use the MAXERROR option for COPY command that ignores invalid lines. Here is the example that ignores up to 100 invalid lines.

```
COPY table_name from 's3://[bucket-name]/[file-path or prefix]' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx' DELIMITER '\t' MAXERROR 100;
```

If the number of invalid lines is more than MAXERROR error count(100), the transaction will be rollbacked.

See the following link for the details of COPY command.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the flag of `NOLOAD` to check for errors before loading the data. This is a faster way to validate the format of your data as it doesn't try to load any data, just parse it.

You can define how many errors you are willing to tolerate with `MAXERROR` flag

If you have more than the `MAXERROR` count, your load will fail and no record is added.

See more information here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: Do you mean that it is not possible to have part of records loaded even when error occurs?

Comment: If the number of errors is smaller than the MAXERROR, the rest will be copied correctly